# Why is my directive creating a new scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Below is a simple directive I wrote to insert a block of HTML stored locally in a script element.

**Here's how it's used:**

```
<body>
   <div my-partial="partial1"></div>
</body>

<script id="partial1" type="text/html">
   <div>
      <button ng-click="OK()">OK</button>
   </div>
</script>
```

The code does do what I want but I see that when the partial template replaces the element using the directive it has the `ng-scope` class on it. This makes me think a new scope was created, but this was not my intention. I just wanted the HTML to be insertd and be part of the existing scope.

*Why is this happening?*

**Here's the directive:**

```
   app.directive("myPartial", ["$compile", function ($compile)
    {
        var def =
        {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope:false,
            compile: function (element, attributes, transclude)
            {
                var tmplID = attributes.myPartial,        //Get templateID
                    markup = $("#" + tmplID).html(),      //Load partial template markup <text node>
                    partial = $("<div>").html(markup);    //Stick markup text into a <div> so it'll become real DOM elements

                partial = partial.contents();             //Don't need that outer <div> anymore

                if (!partial.length) { throw "myPartial: " + tmplID + " not found"; }

                //Replace this element w/ the partial template markup
                element.replaceWith(partial);


                //PostLink
                //---------------------------------------------------------------------
                return function postLink(scope, element, attributes, modelController)
                {
                    //Compile the partial and link it w/ the current scope
                    $compile(partial)(scope);
                }
            }
        };

        return def;
    }]);
```

Thanks for any help or suggested code improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with the post link function. In this case I don't believe I should have one.

This seems to work:

```
 {
        restrict: 'A',  //Attribute
        scope: false,   //Don't create a new scope

        compile: function(element, attributes, transclude)
        {
            //Get partial template
            var partial = $("#" + attributes.asmPartial);

            //Add the partial to the element
            element.html(partial.html());

            //Remove the element leaving only the partial
            element.contents().unwrap();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your second question:**
You cannot access the scope inside the compile function. For the detailed reason read "[Understanding Directives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#injecting-compiling-and-linking-functions)" from the Angular.js Repository Wiki.
Just bind the values regulary to your scope and use the link function to modify the scope if needed.

Comment: That's the case when you set the scope property to **true**, but are you sure it's the case when scope is false?

Comment: scope: true = shared scope between all directive instances additionally to the new scope on the root of the template. You can read it yourself in the documentation (search for my cite). That's how I understand it.

Comment: I was wrong. "scope: false" does not create a scope. See my test: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKhy5/1/

Comment: Yes, I see no scope was created there. So why does my directive create a scope?